# How to add documents to existing index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Am using Elasticsearch 1.4. My requirement is I will have data every hour and that needs to be uploaded. So the approach that I have taken is to create an index - "demo" and upload the data. So, the first hour data gets inserted.  Now, my question is how to append the subsequent hours data into this index.

```
PUT /demo/userdetails/1
{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "message" : "trying out Elastic Search"
}
```

Now I am trying to add another document

```
{"user": "swarna","message":"hi"}
```

Comment: Hi are you get data from which Source?

Answer (score 5):

You simply need to PUT the additional documents. In your example above you did

```
PUT /demo/userdetails/1 { "user" : "kimchy", "message" : "trying out Elastic Search" }
```

Now you would do this:

```
PUT /demo/userdetails/2 {"user": "swarna","message":"hi"}
```

In you command there demo is the index, userdetails is the type, and the number is the document id.  If you omit the document id ES will make one up for you.